# Excel 2013 cut and insert in VBA is not resizing named ranges if the last entry is what's cut

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have a spreadsheet where I have a sheet named "Lists" that contains a number of named ranges. These named ranges are teams of coworkers. I've set up a command button where once pressed it will take the value entered in "H30" (coworkers name) and the value in H31 (managers name) and will select the coworkers name in the team list, cut, and insert them into the team of the manager entered into "H31" (it's for managers to conveniently move people to other teams).

This I have all set up and it works fine, with Excel automatically resizing the named ranges so that all the functions tied to them (ie. combo boxes etc) still work right. However, I run into a problem when the coworker is the LAST coworker in the team. Using cut/insert in VBA doesn't resize the named range that they were cut from, leaving a blank space on the end.

How can I go about having the named range still resize properly since it DOES do so if the coworkers name is cut from anywhere else in the named range. Is there a simple way to do this? If not the below is the approach I want to do, but am not sure how:

Find which named range the entry in "H30" appears in

If statement to check if the value in "H30" matches the last entry in the named range(This I have working)

Resize range after cutting entry(Also have working)

Identifying the range the coworker is coming from is my main issue, and I've tried using a loop like the following to go through each named range:

```
Dim nm As Name

For Each nm In Worksheets("Lists").Names
     If Not Intersect(Range("H30"), nm.RefersToRange) Is Nothing Then
          'Do things
     End If
Next nm
```

I obtained the above from examples elsewhere, but it doesn't seem to ever find the range. No errors are generated either. Are there other approaches I can take to find which named range a value is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Find which named range the entry in "H30" appears in, use 
`Worksheets("Lists").Range("H30").Name.Name`

Cutting a row/column automatically adjust the dynamic range formual. So if you cut something from bottom/top, its gone. Instead of cutting copy cells and clear contents. Hope You are using `CountA` in your named range.

Comment: I wasn't aware of using .Name twice like that, thanks. I also forgot about CountA. Thanks this helped me finish what I needed.